# Android platform-tools r25 on Windows fails gradle's "connectedCheck" with "com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin, platform-tools

We've just set up a new build system, with Windows on a hosted machine.  Setting up the Android system went completely fine until I tried to run some tests on it.  To be ok on a hosted environment, the emulator must be one of the slow ABI emulators, set up and installed with,

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-23,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
echo no | android create avd --force -n ci-Nexus -t android-23 --abi "default/armeabi-v7a"
```

and then started with

```
start emulator -ports 5702,5703 -avd ci-Nexus -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save
```

and then the gradle command is a simple

```
gradlew connectedCheck
```

after compilation, when it comes to actually connecting,

```
connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

with my Android environment being,

```
cat android\tools\source.properties | grep Revision
  Pkg.Revision=25.2.2
cat android\platform-tools\source.properties | grep Revision
  Pkg.Revision=25.0.0
cat android\build-tools\23.0.3\source.properties | grep Revision
  Pkg.Revision=23.0.3
```

If I get the previous version of the SDK, r24, https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r24-windows.zip, connectedCheck works fine.  For us, we're not in desperate need of anything in the r25 version of the platform-tools, so we're staying with 24, which works, for now, but r25 definitely breaks this for us.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically *need* to use Android's r25 platform tools, their r24 version works fine in this environment.  Direct download link is https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r24-windows.zip (unzip and overwrite android/platform-tools with its contents)*.

* If you're downgrading the platform tools package, you should probably downgrade the tools package as well, r24.4.1 is our one of choice.  Direct download https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r24.4.1-windows.zip (same as platform-tools, unzip and overwrite android/tools).